# Trouble returning an array value

Tags: c++, arrays

I keep getting an error code saying `jeb` has redefined itself and changing int to `float` or `double` doesn't work. This is meant to be a random number generator and my array is messing up.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int generate();
int numb();

int main()
{
    int num = numb();
    cout << num << endl;
    cout << endl;

    int gen = generate();
    cout << gen << endl;
    cout << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

int generate(float *jeb[])
{
    int jeb [20] = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int rng = rand() % numb() + 1;
        jeb[i] = rng;
        return jeb;
    }
}

int numb()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "Enter maximum number: ";
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a co-routine

Comment: you have one jeb as parameter and another jeb as local variable

Comment: You also say you'll return a single `int` and try to reeturn something else...

Comment: The `jeb` in the function argument is one definition.   The `int jeb[20]` is another definition.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the `generate()` function is supposed to do ?  could you tell us what you want the `generate()` function to do exactly (return a single random value or multiple random values ?)

Comment: `rand()` is not from `<random>`. `rand()` is a poor quality prng that shouldnt be used for anything serious, if you want good prngs you should take a look at what can be found in `<random>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems here:

```
int generate(int *jeb[])
{
    int jeb [20] = {};
//...
}
```

Now you have two things called `jeb`.
Let's assume you just want one.
You could send in a pointer and fill it up

```
int generate(int *jeb)
{
//.. fill it up in a for loop
}
```

BUT this says it returns an int...

Instead of pointers, try using an array - you seem to know in advance you have 20 elements:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 20> generate()
{
    std::array<int, 20> jeb;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int rng = rand() % numb() + 1;
        jeb[i] = rng;
        return jeb; //Really, wait - we haven't done the whole loop yet
    }
}
```

Another issue might now be obvious: you are returning in the middle of the for loop. Wait until you've finished generating what you need.

```
std::array<int, 20> generate()
{
    std::array<int, 20> jeb;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int rng = rand() % numb() + 1;
        jeb[i] = rng;
    }
    return jeb; // loop now done
}
```